# Sound F-Curve of wave frequencies

Tags: python, audio

by default baking sound to f-curve is going to work with the wave amplitude. If instead of the amplitude I want to map to frequencies of the wave, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

@batFINGER 's add-on sounds like it would probably do what you need:

https://github.com/batFINGER/batFINGER-blender-addons

[image]

---

If I understand you correctly, though, you may just be missing the controls here:

[image]

Comment: Hi, well not really. What I want is to create a graph curve of frequencies (pitch) of the wave instead of the volume (amplitude)
Something like a tuner tool that scans the wav and create a curve of the pitches

Comment: It doesn't really work that way. An audio file is composed of many frequencies at a variety of amplitudes. Perhaps you could elaborate what you mean by "a curve of the pitches."